# confusion about definition of improper integral

Tags: calculus

I'm reading Buck's advanced calculus, it gives two definitions of improper integral when the underlying function is unbounded.

Definition 1: when $D$ is a bounded set, but $f$ is unbounded. Let $f_n(p)=\min\{n, f(p)\}$ be a sequence of truncated function $f_n$. If $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int\int_D f_n$ exist, then $\int\int_Df=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int\int_D f_n$.

Definition 2: let $D$ be an open set whose boundary consists of a finite number of piecewise smooth curves and isolated points, and let $f$ be continuous and positive-valued on $D$. Then $\int\int_D f$ converges and has value $c$ if and only if there is  an expanding sequences of closed sets $\{D_n\}$ which converges to $D$ in the sense that every point of $D$ is interior to some set $D_k$ while each $D_k$ lies in the closure of $D$，and such that $f$ is bounded on each $D_k$ and $c=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int\int_{D_n} f$.

I'm wondering are the two definitions equivalent when $D$ is an open set whose boundary consists of a finite number of piecewise smooth curves and isolated points, and $f$ is continuous and positive-valued on $D$? If it is, can that be proved rigorously? Thanks.